# 0000-00-00 00:00:00 entered as MySQL DateTime

Tags: mysql

Below is the CREATE TABLE statement used to create my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data_received` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `edit_time` datetime NOT NULL}
```

Below is how data is saved in table if 'edit_time' value is not provided:

```
id  edit_time
1   0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Now, if I execute the following statement:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR , edit_time, NOW( ) ) AS diff_in_hours
FROM data_received;
```

I get result: `NULL`

Can someone please help me understand what is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because **`0000-00-00 00:00:00`** is not a valid `DATETIME` expression accepted by the function.

Please check [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff).

Answer (score 2):

Use this method to keep edit-time in mysql

```
`edit_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Auto-update time'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please explain how "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" functions/works?

Comment: @ShahriarNKhondokar: If you use UPDATE statement to modify data in a table, `edit_time` column will be updated to the current time,
so you won't need to insert/update value of `edit_time` directly to the database. and `edit_time` value will be always valid.

Answer (score 2):

Mysql tends to insert rubbish in an attempt to be "helpful". Best to tell it not to do that by settings mysql to STRICT mode so it behaves more like a database should.

```
SET sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES'
```

For details please read the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html).

Answer (score 1):

`0000-00-00 00:00:00` will probably interpreted as `null`. And comparing `null` in a `TIMESTAMPDIFF` will lead to `null` result.

MySQL doc says

> In MySQL, the zero date is defined as '0000-00-00', even though this date is itself considered invalid.

Answer (score 0):

There is no zeroth of zero in year zero, so you cannot calculate the time since then:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', NOW())
```

> NULL

Apparently MySQL does not have a problem with year 0 itself, as this returns a result:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '0000-01-01 00:00:00', NOW())
```

> 17643758